# How to use the data of one table in the database of the other table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I have 2 tables in my database, one for user details which generates GUID and the other table for login details. How do I take the GUID of the user in this query

```
     SqlConnection conlog = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["loginConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conlog.Open();
    Session["New"] = null;
    string idQuery = "Select ID from [Table] where Username='"+Label1.Text+"'";
    SqlCommand idd = new SqlCommand(idQuery, conlog);
    string strQuery = "update logindata set LogoutTime='"+DateTime.Now+"' where UserName='"+Label1.Text+"'  ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conlog);

   DateTime.Now.ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Redirect("Loginform.aspx");
        conlog.Close();
```

When I'm taking the user name in this query, all the logout times for the user changes to the last logout time.

This is the screen shot of the logout details:

[image]

Comment: Your table logindata misses an important piece of information. You need to store in any new record you create there also an unique SessionID that identifies the session of your user. Then, when you need to write the logout info, you should use that SessionID to identify in your table the unique record for that user session

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code:

```
update logindata
set LogoutTime=NEW_DATE
where UserName=USER_NAME;
```

Says: For every record with UserName equal to USER_NAME set LogoutTime to NEW_DATE.

However you want to update only single record thus you need to identify specific login details. The most straightforward solution is to add column with SessionId/LoginId etc. and change query to:

```
update logindata
set LogoutTime=NEW_DATE
where SessionId=SESSION_ID and UserName=USER_NAME;
```

If you can guarantee that SessionId is unique then you can remove comparsion with UserName.

Another solution is to update only record with latest LoginTime, for example:

```
update logindata
set LogoutTime=NEW_DATE
order by LoginTime desc
limit 1;
```

You don't need to add new column this way.

Comment: so how exactly do i use that guID from user detail table in logindata table.. Please help me as i'm new to this.. and i have to sumbit this project.

Comment: If you want to find user by ID in `logindata` table then you need to extract ID from `idd` and put it in `strQuery`. However I'm not sure if I understand _use that guID_ correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you keep multiple records per user in your logout details table, you should specify a way to update the selected record only either by adding new field say (SessionID) or you can use your existing login time. See updates on you example below.

```
// Uncomment next line and update LoginTime variable to hold your Login Time as you inserted in Login Tables upon user login.
// LoginTime =
SqlConnection conlog = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["loginConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conlog.Open();
Session["New"] = null;
string idQuery = "Select ID from [Table] where Username='" + Label1.Text + "'";
SqlCommand idd = new SqlCommand(idQuery, conlog);
string strQuery = "update logindata set LogoutTime='" + DateTime.Now + "' where UserName='" + Label1.Text + "' AND LoginTime = '" + LoginTime + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conlog);

DateTime.Now.ToString());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Response.Redirect("Loginform.aspx");
conlog.Close();
```

Comment: wont it change the logout time for all users who login at same time.?

Comment: No The query has two conditions in Where Clause one for UserName and one for LoginTime so only one record will be updated provided that you do not allow multiple records for the same user at exactly the same time.

Comment: Can u tell me how to update LoginTime variable to hold Login Time. As i'm new to this i dont know what this means.

Comment: Where in your code you save a new record in Logout details table? In this place you suppose to save the current data and time as a field "LoginTime". You may keep this value in session variable like Session["LoginTime"]. Then in my code above you can make the second line like this LoginTime = Session["LoginTime"]. That's all.

Comment: This is my code of Login form. please view it and tell me. please thanks
https://imgur.com/uElwBxF